# django use timedelta in template

Tags: python, django

I am new django. I have the following code to get the current time and my filter is to convert the string date to dateformat and convert it to solar calendar. Is there any way to find the date of tomorrow in the template and not in any python file?

```
{% now 'Y-m-d' as value %}
<script>
    var today = "{{ value|dateCustomFilter }}";
    // var tomorrow = ?
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such filter in Django by default. You could define a custom filter to add an arbitrary days to a date like [builtin add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter add to integers.

like:

```
var today = "{{ value|addDays:1|dateCustomFilter }}"
```

You could also define a custom template tag or pass it via normal template variables.